# PyQt5 QStackedWidget

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qstackedwidget

Через `Qt Designer` сделал форму. Точку входа перенес в другой файл (там же и описывается функционал).

Не могу понять почему определяя событие нажатия на кнопку и устанавливая `stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)` не происходит переход на другую страницу.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_M(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(531, 320)
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(Form)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 491, 271))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);")
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 40, 71, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 160, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 160, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 50, 101, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Main Window"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Second_W"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Main_W"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Second Window"))



from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from simple.gui import Ui_M


class MainClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_M):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.Push)

    def Push(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_M()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вы создали дизайн и изменили его программно с какой целью?

Comment: Потом вы наследуете Ui_M в MainClass этого не нужно делать MainClass вы не используете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно делать так:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#from simple.gui import Ui_M
from simple import Ui_M                  #  у меня модуль simple.py в томже катклоге что и main.py

class MainClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_M):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.Push)

    def Push(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainClass()                                  # <<<-----
    w.show()                                         # <<<-----

#    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
#    ui = Ui_M()
#    ui.setupUi(Form)
#    Form.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**simple.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_M(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(531, 320)
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(Form)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 491, 271))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);")
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 40, 71, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 160, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 160, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 50, 101, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Main Window"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Second_W"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Main_W"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Second Window"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: S. Nick Здравствуйте, я несколько не сомневаюсь в вашем авторитете) но разве здесь нужно множественное наследование?                                                       class MainClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_M):

Comment: @Александр есть разные варианты, я предпочитаю такой как описан в примере.

Comment: Буду разбираться сидеть... Туча классов в pyqt. Начал только осваивать. Господа, спасибо за ответы!

Comment: @Артем а с чем разбираться ? спросите что не понятно.

Comment: Спасибище огромнейшее!!!  Арбайтен ))) Сей час проанализирую код. Вся конструкция взята с ютуба, поэтому есть непонятки (там нормальной реализации чет не увидел по stackedWidget).